# Why I have to double parameters with wendelladriel/laravel-validated-dto in store request?

Tags: laravel, dto

I make an API for storing data in the task_user table:

```
CREATE TABLE `task_user` (
`id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`task_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
`user_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
`team_lead` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`expires_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

using vsc Version: 1.85.1 and Thunder Client plugin.

I have a route

```
POST            api/tasks/{task_id}/task-store-many-users/{user_id} ..................................................................... tasks.taskManyUsersStore › Api\TaskUserController@taskManyUsersStore
```

with 2 parameters, task_id and user_id and I fill sample data in next way :

[image]

I use wendelladriel/laravel-validated-dto 3.3 plugin, which has defined :

```
namespace App\DTO;

use DateTime;
use WendellAdriel\ValidatedDTO\Casting\BooleanCast;
use WendellAdriel\ValidatedDTO\Casting\CarbonCast;
use WendellAdriel\ValidatedDTO\Casting\IntegerCast;
use WendellAdriel\ValidatedDTO\Casting\StringCast;
use WendellAdriel\ValidatedDTO\SimpleDTO;

class TaskUserDTO extends SimpleDTO
{
    public int $task_id;
    public int $user_id;
    public bool $team_lead;
    public ?datetime $expires_at = null;
    public ?datetime $created_at = null;

    protected function defaults(): array
    {
        //
        return [];
    }

    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'task_id' => new IntegerCast(),
            'user_id' => new IntegerCast(),
            'team_lead' => new BooleanCast,
            'expires_at' => new CarbonCast,
            'created_at' => new CarbonCast
        ];
    }
}
```

So using dto in controller :

```
public function taskManyUsersStore(Request $request,  int $taskId, int $userId): JsonResponse {
    try {
        $data = TaskUserDTO::fromRequest($request);
```

I got error :

```
{
  "message": "Cannot assign null to property App\\DTO\\TaskUserDTO::$task_id of type int",
  "exception": "TypeError",
  "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/TasksWithSearch/vendor/wendelladriel/laravel-validated-dto/src/SimpleDTO.php",
  "line": 237,
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/TasksWithSearch/vendor/wendelladriel/laravel-validated-dto/src/SimpleDTO.php",
      "line": 156,
      "function": "validatedData",
      "class": "WendellAdriel\\ValidatedDTO\\SimpleDTO",
      "type": "->"
```

To avoid this error, I need to add  task_id and user_id parameters in Data Form - it seems to me that it is not valid to pass any parameter twice.
Sure, the Thunder Client plugin is a tool, but in real work, any parameter must be passed twice. In which way can it be salved?